# Проблема с формами html

Tags: php, html

Есть файл form.html с таким содержанием

```
<form action="action.php" name="myform" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="mytext" size="50"> 
    <input name="Submit" type=submit value="Отправить данные">
</form>
```

И файл action.php с содержанием

```
<?php
    $text =  ($_GET['mytext'];
    echo $text; // Выводим содержимое текстового поля
```

После заполнения формы и отправки запроса ничего не происходит. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема? Интернет не помог. Бился около часа..

Comment: Я думал может быть нужно что то изменить в настройках php или apache, но никакого упоминания об этом не нашёл в интернете..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выше верно сказали, у вас стоит лишняя скобка перед методом запроса.

```
<form action="action.php" name="myform" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="mytext" size="50"> 
    <input name="Submit" type=submit value="Отправить данные">
</form>

<?php
    $text = $_POST['mytext'];
    echo $text; // Выводим содержимое текстового поля
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

[[@istimbi](/users/18061/istimbi)](/users/18061/istimbi), в HTTP существует два основных метода запроса (на самом деле их около десятка, просто они значительно реже используются): GET и POST. POST предназначен для передачи данных, GET, грубо говоря, для уточнения запроса.

У вас в форме принудительно указан метод POST:

```
<form action="action.php" name="myform" method="post">
```

В этом случае (в случае получения POST-запроса) все пришедшие данные PHP разместит в глобальном массиве `$_POST`, где и надо их ловить. Если бы атрибут method не был указан (или был бы указан GET), пришедшие данные оказались бы в `$_GET`.

То есть в конкретно данном случае необходимо либо заменить `$_GET` на `$_POST`, либо изменить метод отправки данных, отредактировав тег формы.

Comment: Это не помогло:-( изменил в $text =  ($_POST['mytext']; Но всё осталось как прежде - пустая страница..

Comment: @istimbi, надо убрать открывающую скобку или поставить закрывающую, без этого все должно падать с ошибкой.

Comment: Спасибо.. Я проверял каждое слово на правильность написания. А вот со скобками затупил, извините.